# How can i open google calendar app with pre-filled details from mobile browser?

Tags: google-calendar-api, mobile-browser

How can I open the google calendar app with pre-filled details e.g title, recurring, etc from the mobile browser?

I used the link below and it's not working

https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=event+title&dates=20210718T080010/20210718T083010&ctz=America/Mexico_City&details=book+details&recur=RRULE%3AFREQ%3DWEEKLY%3BCOUNT%3D11%3BBYDAY%3DSU%2CMO%2CTU%2CWE%2CTH%2CFR%2CSA%3B

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. When I access this URL on a mobile browser, the Calendar app opens with the pre-filled details. What kind of device are you using?

Comment: Same for me, it opens the google calendar in the browser, not the app.